# How to get the dynamic height of UIView which contains two or more UILabels vertically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find the dynamic height of a UIView at the run time. So, for this I calculated the run time height of UILabels in it and the constraint constants and add them all to get the desired height. But this doesn't seems to be the correct way of doing it, because in case I alter the count of UILabel or constraints in future then I do have to change the code to calculate the dynamic height. So, is there any way to get the height of UIView at run time with any number of labels and constraints in it?

**MY CODE**

Here **uiview** is UIView of which I need to calculate the dynamic height, **label1** and **label2** are the UILabels in which I inserted text programatically. **height** is a string extension to find dynamic height of UILabel. **label1TopConstraint**, **label1BottonContraint**, **label2BottomConstraint** are constraints IBOutlets.

```
let label1Height = label1.text!.height(withConstrainedWidth: label1.frame.width, font: label1.font)
let label2Height = label2.text!.height(withConstrainedWidth: label2.frame.width, font: label2.font)
uiviewHeight = label1Height + label2Height + label1TopConstraint.constant + label1BottonContraint.constant + label2BottomConstraint.constant
```

Comment: You have labels inside a UIView so you could use the UIView's frame's height property to get the height of the view unless I am missing the point of your question. You can still use frame with autolayout, it just depends on how and when you use it.

Comment: Can you add this code of how you set up the labels with the constraints and also where do you set them up `didLoad`, `willAppear` etc - I don't think adding constraints programmatically or using the storyboard should make a difference but i can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, for miscommunication but I inserted labels from storyboard, but then I added text in the labels programatically, thats why the height of label changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer lies in `layoutIfNeeded` and let me explain why

Consider my storyboard set up to set up a Dynamic height UIView which should set its height automatically based on the UILabels within it, note that I did not set the height anchor and so it gives me constraint errors which you can ignore for now as they will be resolved once we are done setting up.

[image: UIView dynamic height with UILabels autolayout swift iOS]

Next I add two labels to this view which have `numberOfLines = 0`

Top Label constraints

[image: Dynamic height UILabel UIView swift autolayout constraints storyboard]

Bottom Label constraints

[image: UIView dynamic height based on multi line dynamic label height swift iOS autolayout constraints storyboard]

After this, the constraint errors go away and notice the height of the view in which the labels are contained in is `82`:

[image: UIView dynamic view height dynamic label height storyboard autolayout constraints]

Now I add this code which dynamically changes the text in the label

```
class DynamicHeightVC: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    
    var longText = """
    Some really long text that should make the UI label
    expand beyond a few lines and make the UIView expand
    along with it.
    """
    
    var reallyLongText = """
    Some really long text that should make the UI label
    expand beyond a few lines and make the UIView expand
    along with it. Some really long text that should make
    the UI label expand beyond a few lines and make the
    UIView expand along with it.
    """
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        labelOne.text = longText
        labelTwo.text = reallyLongText
        
        print("View height \(myView.frame.height)")
    }
}
```

The output is `View height 82.0` which is the value we saw on the storyboard and it is clearly wrong as the view's height is bigger:

[image: UIView dynamic height multiple UILabels storyboard autolayout constraints]

So the issue is once you change / update the text, the constraints get updated and the frames will get updated at a later / different iteration of the main run loop which might not be useful to you since you want to do some calculations with it now.

If you want the frames to be updated in the next turn of the update cycle within the main run loop, you need to call `view.setNeedsLayout()`.

If you want the frames to be updated immediately, you need to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`

After making this change, the code is as follows:

```
class DynamicHeightVC: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    
    var longText = """
    Some really long text that should make the UI label
    expand beyond a few lines and make the UIView expand
    along with it.
    """
    
    var reallyLongText = """
    Some really long text that should make the UI label
    expand beyond a few lines and make the UIView expand
    along with it. Some really long text that should make
    the UI label expand beyond a few lines and make the
    UIView expand along with it.
    """
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        labelOne.text = longText
        labelTwo.text = reallyLongText
        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        print("Label 1 height \(labelOne.frame.height)")
        print("Label 2 height \(labelTwo.frame.height)")
        print("View height \(myView.frame.height)")
    }
}
```

And now the console displays the correct, updated height:

```
Label 1 height 101.5
Label 2 height 183.0
View height 284.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need those runtime calculations if you already use AutoLayout and can rely on constraints? Here's an example:

A view, containing two labels:

```swift
import UIKit

final class LabelsView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .red

        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.text = "Label 1"
        label1.backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(label1)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
                                     label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                     label1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
                                     label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)])

        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label2.text = "Label 2"
        label2.backgroundColor = .green

        addSubview(label2)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
                                     label2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                     label2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.heightAnchor),
                                     label2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)])
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

An example usage outcome:

[image]

Here's a view that reuses the first one (among others):

```swift
final class AnotherView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .blue

        let labelsView = LabelsView()
        labelsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(labelsView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([labelsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
                                     labelsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                     labelsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10.0)])

        let yetAnotherView = UIView()
        yetAnotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yetAnotherView.backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(yetAnotherView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yetAnotherView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
                                     yetAnotherView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                     yetAnotherView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelsView.heightAnchor),
                                     yetAnotherView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelsView.bottomAnchor,
                                                                         constant: 10.0)])
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

An example usage output:

[image]

Comment: I thought same, but when I used frame.height it is giving not giving me correct results every time.

Comment: First of all, why do you need a frame? If you constrain all your views with AutoLayout, you don't need frames at all – this was the point of my approach. Secondly, if you do need a frame value, mind when you try to get it. If you access it from `init` it won't work, because views are not laid out yet. You can only get correct frame values after views were laid out – i.e. within or before corresponding view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple constraints on multiple labels, you can use UIStackViews vertically or horizontally according to your preference.

Comment: Yeah that could be done, but for some reason I can not use UIStackView. I need to get the height in this UI only.